# Confusion regarding BeautifulSoup's append method

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried to test the below contents. Now I have seen one doubtful things as below:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("<a>Foo</a>")
>>> soup.a.append("Bar")
>>> soup
<a>FooBar</a>
>>> soup.a.contents
[u'Foo', u'Bar']
>>>
```

I am confused why did it came as `[u'Foo', u'Bar']` instead of `[u'FooBar']`?

Can you help me in this concept?

Comment: Fix your code and import NavigableString properly from the BeautifulSoup module (and read the BS docs telling you everything about 'contents' and NavigableString)

Comment: @CRUSADER if i am not wrong, you just edited your answer. when you would be helping someone,try to put full things rather the scattered one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> from BeautiulSoup import NavigableString
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("<a>Foo</a>")
>>> soup.a.contents = [NavigableString(str(soup.a.contents[0]) + 'Bar')]
>>> soup
<a>FooBar</a>
```

Comment: Wkat the differences are between your one and my descripton's one?

Comment: Leave it. I am giving you `+1`